# Angular 8, agm api, WARNING in ./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm-core.js 4538:34-52

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-api, angular-cli-v8, agm

I am currently working on a project in angular 8.  I was attempting to set up a Google maps API and completed:

```
1.maps.service.ts
2.app.module.ts
3.app.component.ts
4.app.component.html
```

**the errors I'm getting are:**

```
WARNING in 
./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm- 
core.js 4538:34-52
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not 
found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in 
./node_modules/@agm/core/fesm5/agm- 
core.js 4538:120-128
"export 'ɵɵinject' was not found in 
'@angular/core'
```

**Versions:**

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 10.16.3
agm 1.1.0
```

From what I have seen this is due to Angular changing eeinject and eefineInjectable

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I tried some stuff from here:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/issues/147
 by removing the ee from all of the instances in that path.  That got rid of the errors but left me with a black screen on my local host.

Comment: switch to agm 1.0.0